# Rails Postgres how to query a jsonb column for empty objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

How do I get all the empty records for a jsonb column with Active Record ?

Comment: Are you looking for all rows where the jsonb column is `null`? Or, are you looking for all rows where the jsonb column is an empty object '{}'? Some example code/sql would help here.

Comment: I am looking for all the rows where the jsonb column is an empty object '{}' . I actually tried Active Record query interface Model.where.not(my_column: {})

Comment: Have you tried Model.where("my_column = '{}'")

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can query for empty objects in a JSONB column using the following syntax:

```
Model.where("column = '{}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converting the json to string, and count the length. Empty json will return 2. This works for both {} and [].
E.g. To return empty comment

```
Model.where("length(column::text) <= 2").count
```